# How to console.log number in the following format?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm trying to display numbers in the following format can you please tell me what is wrong?
Can not use div. As i'm printing this in the console.

I for `n = 5`:

```
           1

         1 2 1

       1 2 3 2 1

     1 2 3 4 3 2 1

   1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

I have tried the following code:

```
n = 10
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    console.log("0" + j + " ");
  }
  console.log("<br />");
}
```

```js
n = 10
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    console.log("0" + j + " ");
  }
  console.log("<br />");
}
```

But it displays something like this:

```
1

1 2 

1 2 3 

1 2 3 4 

1 2 3 4 5 

1 2 3 4 5 6 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: this is not console log

Comment: Do your homework from yourself.

Comment: You need add some `\t` to get indentation

Comment: Do you *really* want `010` in your last line? But please: learn the difference between the document and the console, look for alternatives to `document.write()` (for example setting the `textContent`), learn about styling elements with CSS.

Comment: No i don't want 0 in the numbers.

Comment: "*[I cannot] use div*" - why, what constraints are you working with? That's important information that needs to be in the question. And if you "*don't want 0 in the numbers*" why are you adding `0` to the numbers?

Comment: @DavidThomas Edited the question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for your Task. It takes numbers from 1 to declared. Also puts some space at the beginning of each row. You need to declare a string at the beginning of each row and then add all elements to it. When all loops are done, you can print it in console with `console.log`.

```js
var n = 10 // Declaring number of rows

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  var row = ''; //declaring text variable for current row 
  
  for (var x = n - i; x >= 1; x--) {
    row += '  '; //adding spaces in begining of the row
  }
  
  for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    row += ' ' + j; // numbers which increase up to middle
  }
  
  for (var k = i - 1; k >= 1; k--) {
    row += ' ' + k; // adding rest of the numbers to the row
  }
  
  console.log(row); //displaying whole row
}
```

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you for your comment. I wanted to add an answer as fast as possible :D What do you think now, after my edit?

Comment: Down-vote removed; but - for future reference - you don't have to be the [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) in order to have the accepted, or most-upvoted, answer to a question.

Comment: @DavidThomas thank you for your time. Your link is very informative and everyone must read it before joining the community.

Answer (score 0):

for the algorithm point of view you have the forward loop but you missed the downward loop

adding it more the indentation from your first version of the question :

```js
var n = 10

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
    document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
  }
  for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    document.write(" " + j + " ");
  }
  for (var j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
    document.write(" " + j + " ");
  }
  document.write("<br />");
}
```

P.S. It is the very first time I write code in javascript ;-)

Comment: Your also correct but i'm unable to think of a logic to add the indentation.